# Graphiql doesn't substitute variable in super simple mutation

Tags: go, graphql, graphiql

I'm using the Graphiql Go GUI. I'm trying to create mutation that creates a user. However, I get an error saying that an email has not been provided.

If I view the request, it doesn't include the substituted value. And because of that it doesn't ever make it far enough in the server to create a user.

I'm wondering the proper syntax for this. I've read the docs and several responses from the community and this looks to be the correct syntax.

```
mutation CreateUser($email: String!) {
  createUser(email: $email) {
    id
    email
  }
}
```

query variables:

```
{
  "email": "test@test.com"
}
```

type:

```
var RootMutation = graphql.NewObject(graphql.ObjectConfig{
    Name: "RootMutation",
    Fields: graphql.Fields{
        "createUser": &graphql.Field{
            Type:        UserType,
            Description: "Creates a new user",
            Args: graphql.FieldConfigArgument{
                "email": &graphql.ArgumentConfig{
                    Type: graphql.NewNonNull(graphql.String),
                },
            },
            Resolve: func(params graphql.ResolveParams) (interface{}, error) {
                email, err := params.Args["email"].(string)
                log.Println(err)
                log.Println(email)

                // handle creating user
            },
        },
    },
})
```

Error:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable \"$email\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 21
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't understand why if there are no errors on the client GUI side (graphiql) why it wouldn't be sending along the email to the backend.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Looks promising, the error is a graphQL Error. It is checked before entering your resolver.
You could try to enter `mutation {createUser(email:"test") {email}}` in your graphiql

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I ended up doing and it seems to work.

Comment: in my case even the graphiql is giving error. i am using apollo client and the systax used by @Locco0_0 doesn't work in apollo but it works on graphiql . any solution on how to pass a variable. My server is on Golang too..